# What are the little white eggs on rose leaf?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, pests, roses

Somes weeks ago rose food /w bad things killer was sprinkled on the ground. The three roses were, just a little over a week ago, hacked back for better access to attempt to clear myrtle that had invaded the area. The white is (was) on just rose. 
Location of plants is [Julian, CA, US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian,_California)

Not a photographer, but here is the best quality photo that I have on the leaf.[image: white eggs on leaf]

[image: Later photo of the only other spot, removed from the trash]

Comment: @Stephie dug in the trash and tried to get another better image.

Comment: Now *that’s* a great photo. And not woolly aphids, imho.

Comment: @C.W.Holeman II Did you chance use some type of water dissolving powder based fertilizer to your roses? Also, get very close to those clusters and check to see if there are strands connecting them; I suggest using a magnifying glass if you have one. Also, try removing a cluster (with gloves) and place them on a plate then add some water; do they dissolve in the water?

Comment: @C.W.HolemanII  I have to ask what the heck was 'bad things killer'?  Please, applying stuff like 'bad things killer' is the worst mistake we humans can do.  Will make HUGER problems for you sooner and later.  Please tell us what you have used for pesticides as well as fertilizer.  You chopped up your roses a week ago?  During the time of year when they have the opportunity to make food for themselves and all their processes?  When a plant is weakened; drought, too much water, too much anything...too much pruning, that plant has put out a neon sign saying, "come eat me"...

Comment: I am also seeing too many salts in your soil.  The browning edges highlight that problem well.   Please tell us your maintenance habits and what you have added to the soil.  These eggs and whatever insect that laid them are NOT your problem.

Comment: Just looked at your pictures again.  I do believe I see spider mite.  Do you see the fine fine webbing at the tip of the leaves in the upper pictures?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to wait for your response to my comment. However, I am just going to go ahead and give you my theory. I believe these to be Cixiids eggs:

http://blog.growingwithscience.com/2009/09/bug-of-the-week-cixiids/

Comment: So is it important to get rid of these eggs or let them be?

Comment: Larvae them be unless they're damaging the roots by feeding.

Comment: @stormy Their fine, you can simply spray them off with a hose or leave them be.